# NoSuchMethodError for obfuscated openCV library

Tags: android, opencv, proguard, android-proguard

I'm using the OpenCV library for Android for my app. I use `minify` and `proguard` for the release version of my app. This is my `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *;}
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep class com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.*
-ignorewarnings
```

While using the app as a release version, I sometimes run into this error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/opencv/core/CvException;.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V"
       at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_submat(Mat.java)
       at org.opencv.core.Mat.submat(Mat.java:839)
       at one.realnote.app.ImageAnchor.registerForDetectionAndTraking1(ImageAnchor.java:600)
.
.
.
```

If I decompile the release apk, I get this as the content of `CvException.java`:

```
package org.opencv.core;


public class CvException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x1L;
}
```

which does not have an `init` method or rather a constructor like the exception says. The correct content of the class should be this:

```
package org.opencv.core;

public class CvException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CvException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CvException [" + super.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

So how do I tell my proguard to leave the CvException class or even better all of the OpenCv code just like it is and neither obfuscate nor minify it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you have to add this line in your proguard file:

```
-keep class org.opencv.** { *; }
```

You don't need to obfuscate opencv modules!